# ADO Connection to SQL Server drop down does not always show servers

Tags: sql-server, connection, ado

When using the ADO Connection dialog to build a connection string, the database server does not always show in the drop down of available servers. On some machines it does - on others it doesn't. I'm taking here about the local server as well - not just networked servers.

Who knows the magic?

Thanks

Ray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge that is reliant on SQL Browser.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165724%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

So some instances may reside on machines that do not have the service running, or may not be listening for remote requests, or may not have the proper port open.

Comment: Yes that sounds sensible doesn't it? Except I just looked on my machine and the service is running - but I can't see the servers...

Comment: Sure, but if your machine is running SQL Browser, and the other instances are not listening for remote connections, are listening on another port than you are using to browse, or are listening on a port that is not open or not accessible to you, you still won't be able to see them.